# How to set prawn pdf filename in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

What i have is the controller action responding to html and pdf file format like this:

```
   def detail
      @record = Model.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html # detail.html.erb
         format.pdf { render :layout => false } #detail.pdf.prawn
      end
   end
```

but when i get the file it comes with the name: `1.pdf` `2.pdf` depending on the `params[:id]` how do i set the filename to `myfile.pdf`

--UPDATE--

Example of my `detail.pdf.prawn` file

```
pdf.font "Helvetica"
pdf.image open("http://localhost:3000/images/myImage.png"),:position => :left,:width=>100
pdf.text "some text"
pdf.table(someData,:cell_style => { :border_width => 0.1,:border_color=> 'C1C1C1' }) do |table|
    table.row(0).style :background_color => 'D3D3D3'
    table.column(0..1).style(:align => :left)
    table.column(2..4).style(:align => :center)
    table.column(0).width = 100
    table.column(1).width = 250
    table.column(3..4).width = 68
    table.row(2).column(0..2).borders = []
    table.row(2).column(3).style(:font_style => :bold, :align => :right)
end
```

and the `format.pdf { render :layout => false }` in the controller renders de pdf file with the instructions on `detail.pdf.prawn`

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on fl00r's answer, If your using prawnto, the pdf setup params can go in your controller, including the filename.

```
def detail
 @record = Model.find(params[:id])
 prawnto :prawn => { :page_size => 'A4', 
                     :left_margin => 50,    
                     :right_margin => 50,   
                     :top_margin => 80,    
                     :bottom_margin => 50}, 
             :filename => @record.name, :inline => true #or false


      respond_to do |format|
         format.html # detail.html.erb
         format.pdf { render :layout => false } #detail.pdf.prawn
      end
   end
```

If you are creating lot's of different pdf's with prawnto, you would probably move the config out into it's own method. but if your only doing the one, in the controller is fine.

NOTE: the PDF url will still display e.g. 1.pdf But when they save the PDF the filename param will show up in the save box dialog.

Comment: getting this error `syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
    prawnto :prawn => :filename => @hotel_shell.address.hotel_code`

Comment: Figured it out. Basically had to add `{ :page_size => 'A4' }, `

Answer (score 0):

```
prawnto :filename => "myfile", :prawn => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Shoul i do this on the view `detail.pdf.prawn` or should i do this up in the controller `detail` action ?

Comment: Check the update of this question i added the content of my `detail.pdf.prawn` file

Answer (score 0):

Really thanks, this post really help my *old* pdf way. There is another way to using `prawn` of Rails. You can check oh this [link](http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/). Not mine, but a good tutorial for making it. Just saying probably for anyone that still confuse how to make it.

I was using this method before, then I moved on method from that link. Really fun for doing some research about it.

Answer (score 0):

If prawn-rails or prawn_plus you may do following in controller.

```
headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"myfile.pdf\""
```